# how to write an array to file in ruby

Tags: php, ruby, arrays, file-io

I have arrays like below

```
Array ( [0] => abuse@peterstar.net [2] => hostmaster@peterstar.net [3] => noc@peterstar.net )
```

and i need to convert it into below format

```
:abuse@peterstar.net,hostmaster@peterstar.net,noc@peterstar.net
```

i know this in php is easy as below

```
file_put_contents($file, ":".implode(",", $emails)."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

but how do i do this in ruby?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: That's not an array.  After fixing it, please check that it's valid (e.g., in IRB), then edit.  If you'd prefer, just write it as `[ob0, ob1,...,obN]` where each `obi` is a Ruby object.  Note the URLs are strings, so must be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @Ultimater i am know php i and trying to modify a php script to ruby.

Comment: @CarySwoveland above is output of php not ruby in ruby [abuse@peterstar.net, hostmaster@peterstar.net, noc@peterstar.net]

Comment: Are you saying `Array ( [0] => abuse@peterstar.net [2] => hostmaster@peterstar.net [3] => noc@peterstar.net )` is a string?  If so, just enclose it in single or double quotes, remove the reference to arrays and all should be clear.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the **[File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html)** class.

```
File.open(yourfile, 'w') { |file| file.write(":#{your_array.join(',')}") }
```

If you want to append text to the file, you need to open the file in "append" mode.

```
File.open(yourfile, 'a') { |file| file.write(":#{your_array.join(',')}") }
```

Comment: but i need output like this    :abuse@peterstar.net,hostmaster@peterstar.net,noc@peterstar.net  :abuse@peterstar.net,hostmaster@peterstar.net,noc@peterstar.net  :abuse@peterstar.net,hostmaster@peterstar.net,noc@peterstar.net  :abuse@peterstar.net,hostmaster@peterstar.net,noc@peterstar.net

Comment: user3155632, you need to clarify your question by editing it, not by trying to elaborate in comments.  Do it now or your question will almost certainly be killed by moderators.  It may be too late as it is.

Comment: @user3155632 You mean the append mode?

Comment: Thanks @xdazz it worked this what i am missing :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to store the data in a more common format like YAML.

```
array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

# write file
File.open('filename.yml', 'w') { |f| YAML.dump(array, f) }

# read file
array = File.open('filename.yaml') { |f| YAML::load(f) }
```

Comment: Use `File.write('filename.yaml', array.to_yaml)` and `YAML.load_filel('filename.yaml')`

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how does one convert the string:

```
str = "Array ( {[0] => abuse@peterstar.net}, {[2] => hostmaster@peterstar.net},\
 {[3] => noc@peterstar.net} )"
```

to the string:

```
":abuse@peterstar.net,hostmaster@peterstar.net,noc@peterstar.net"
```

a regex is needed:

```
':' + str.scan(/(?:=> )([^}]*)/).join(',')
```

The need for `:` and `.join(',')` should be obvious.  Let's look at the regex that produces

```
  str.scan(/.*?(?:=> )([^}]*)/)
    # => [["abuse@peterstar.net"], ["hostmaster@peterstar.net"], ["noc@peterstar.net"]]
```

I am not a regex expert, so would welcome any corrections or suggestions for improvement.

- `(?:=> )` is a "non-capture" group (because of `?:`), which looks for `"=> "`.
- `([^}]*)` is a capture group that accepts all characters until it meets a `"}"`.

Answer (score 0):

The ruby equivalent of `implode` is `join`. The ruby equivalent of the `.` operator on strings is `+`. The ruby equivalent of writing to a file:

```
File.open(yourfile, 'w') do |file|
  file.write ':' + yourarray.join(',') + "\n" 
end
```